# Effective way to resolve the EventQueue, CPU and memory load related issue

Tags: publishing, performance, event-queue

I have hundreds of thousands items in Sitecore, sometimes it needs to publish all of them and as the result CPU and memory are overloaded. The reason of the perfomance issue is a huge amount of items in EventQueue table.

I know there is configurable agent in Sitecore responsible for cleaning EventQueue table in database. There are also some SQL scripts to clean out the table manually. But I'm trying to find out more handy solution as it's not convenient on the production environment to run custom script or wait till the agent to do the job.

Solutions I can think of are:

- Implementing a custom handler on publish:end event
- Creating a scheduled SQL job to run the clean up script
- Limiting the size of the EventQueue table in SQL Server
- Runing cleanup agent more often (e.g. per 1/2 hour)

**Update**:
As I've found that Sitecore introduced `<IntervalToKeep>hh:mm:ss</IntervalToKeep>` setting in Sitecore, so the best solution that I see is to:

- Set `<IntervalToKeep>01:00:00</IntervalToKeep>`
- Creating a scheduled SQL job to run the clean up script (http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/cms_tuning_guide_sc70-usletter.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

You can usually improve this by tuning the settings for our queues.
A good post in this can be found here: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/sitecore-event-queue-how-to-clean-it-and-why/

What I normally do:

- On the CM: clean the eventqueue very aggressively
- On the CD:

  - poll the eventqueue less aggressively
  - disable the eventqueue cleaning

Example:

On CM: change `<DaysToKeep>1</DaysToKeep>` to `<IntervalToKeep>01:00:00</IntervalToKeep>` for the `CleanupEventQueue`

On CD: set the `<processingInterval>00:00:02</processingInterval>` to `<processingInterval>00:02:00</processingInterval>` for the `<eventQueue>`
and disable the `CleanupEventQueue` by setting its interval to `00:00:00`

By tuning these parameters we were able to get a site with millions of items published.

That said, publishing all of your items regularly is never a good idea. There are always items/trees that don't need publishing. Your ultimate solution is to think about that and come up with a way to avoid the full publish.

*Edit*: (based on comment)

The CleanupEventQueue is disabled on the CD because the CM does the job. No need for several instances to start this job. We did see better performance and smaller queues with these settings. Of course, you can tune them as it fits best in your solution.

The larger processing interval does indeed mean that CD's might/will detect content changes later. And yes, the bigger this interval, the bigger the risk of inconsistancy. So this is surely something to consider and see what is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Could you clarify the solution for CD instances. Am I right that `CleanupEventQueue` agent is not needed on CDs due to CM's performs this job? Do you see any significant benefit in perfomance with this change?
Can the setting `<processingInterval>00:02:00</processingInterval>` bring some inconsistancy between CDs instances up to 2 minutes in this case?

Comment: Added to the answer..  still, as you will probably notice, all this tuning will help you but it's not a magical solution. The real magic is figuring out how to make the publish smaller ;)

Comment: Normally we do not publish all items in Sitecore but sometimes it is needed after some changes in the external system and then a syncronization of related items in Sitecore. As the end of such sync I just run publish these items and the EventQueue table gets tons of records.

Comment: You are saying that your solution allows to publish millions of items without any perfomance issue and I don't understand it in details. Let's imagine you have 1000000 items in Sitecore, you run publish, EventQueue is overloaded and CM is unresponsive. As the result Cleanup agent can't be started both from CD and CM Sitecore instances and the issue cannot be self-resolved. Am I correct here?

Comment: I'm not saying it will solve all your performance issues. It will improve the situation, but to solve it you need to find another solution. Which we won't be able to do here (at least not with the information given). As said in the answer, I would still search for a solution where you don't need this publish scenario. Regularly importing such amounts of items into a Sitecore master database - with the need to publish them.. that is never a good idea. You might consider a data provider or something like that.. but as said, rather hard to give you the exact best solution without all context.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize memory usage by enabling **Sitecore Interning**. To do this enable this two settings:

```
<setting name="Interning.Enabled" value="false"/>
<setting name="Interning.InternKnownFieldValues" value="false"/>
```

and add your custom fields, that you know can have a lot of duplicated values, to this list:

```
<fieldIdsToIntern />
```

Another thing you can do to optimize memory usage is to configure `MemoryMonitorHook` to clear sitecore cache when it exceeds defined threashold:

```
<hook type="Sitecore.Diagnostics.MemoryMonitorHook, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="Threshold">10GB</param>
    <param desc="Check interval">00:01:00</param>
    <param desc="Minimum time between log entries">00:00:20</param>
    <ClearCaches>true</ClearCaches>
    <GarbageCollect>true</GarbageCollect>
    <AdjustLoadFactor>false</AdjustLoadFactor>
</hook>
```

I recently faced similar problem and wrote a blog post about this. You can read it [here](http://bartlomiejmucha.com/en/blog/memory-optimisation-in-sitecore/).

Comment: Bartłomiej, thanks a lot! I will try to tune `MemoryMonitorHook` in accordance to your post.

Answer (score 1):

That's true. you can use this  option to clean event queue.

If you are facing CPU or memory load issue or may be performance issue so its better to clean few more table as well apart from EventQueue:

- History table using  option
- Publishing queue using  option

For more details see this blog.

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/sitecore-event-queue-how-to-clean-it-and-why/

Comment: You are right, in general History and PublishQueue tables should be cleared as well. In my specific case I have a problem with EventQueue table only and I'm looking for the best solution how to keep this table clear.